# Different Image Size / Crop by Shopname ( Wordpress )

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on an affiliate shop . Well currently I have 8000+ products from over 20 shops .
Since each store now , the product images in various sizes are available , I wonder if i can not set a specific size / cut per shop ?! ( Shop_Catalog & Single_Product ).
A user told me the only way is a PHP-script in the functions.php.
Each Image has the Shopname in the front of the Dataname.
For Example Zalando81237

It should work like this.

If Dataname contains Zalando use this Height / Width / Crop

WooCommerce

any Idea? thx

Comment: You can configure the various image sizes in woocommerce settings (`/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=products&section=display`). There's also a plugin called "regenerate thumbnails" that might be useful. Are you running multiple shops, i.e., 1 wp/woo instance per shop?

Comment: thx. yes i know that but i need multiple sizes because each of the shops sends me different Images. My Affiliate Shop has 20 partnershops and each of them has a different Size. I have to Crop / resize each Image by reconizing them from wich shop they are. ( Dataname )

Comment: Ok, so, your affiliate shop contains all products and images, and the 20 other shops use those images - is that right? Those other shops, are they WooCommerce too? If so, and if you provide images to those shops, just give them the highest resolution image and have their WP/Woo generate the thumbs in the sizes they need. If I got this wrong, could you please explain a bit more on where the images comes from and where they go?

Comment: If I got that backwards (and I probably did) - and the other shops provide the images to your affiliate shop, then I don't see the problem: wouldn't you want the images from those *other* shops to be scaled to uniformly fit the layout on *your* (affiliate) shop? This should happen by default, according to the settings on that woo admin page.

Comment: Okay. I dont know what cms they use. I only publish there products in my Shop ( Woocommerce ). I get them Images from them via CSV. But each Shop has different Image Sizes so i need to resize them all because if not it would very bad on the Catalog Page. The Dataname of the images always contain the shopname for example Zalando123179 ( Zalando = Shop , 123179 ProductID ) So i need a little script wich can reconize the Shop from the images and set the right crop / size settings.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! AFAIK you don't need to know where the images came from or what size they are. If you add/update an image using the WP API, WP itself will automatically generate the catalog and thumbnail images in the size you have specified in the "Woo > Settings > Products" page. I simply call (wp_generate_attachment_metadata)[https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_attachment_metadata] to have it do that. The post should be an attachment to a product, though. Perhaps you could add (some of) the code you now use to add/update such images?

Comment: Thanks :). Atm i do it like this. i go media settings-> add_image_size( 'shop_catalog', '275', '200', array( "center", "center") ); 
add_image_size( 'shop_single', '275', '200', array( "center", "center") );

Comment: then search in Media for the specific shop, then regenerate only these,
and repeat it with different settings ( Width , Height , Crop ) and diffrent shop. But the Products refresh everyday and many get added, so to regenerate with those 20 settings manuelly it takes to long for doing that every day. I thought maybe theres a plugin for this but unfortianly no :( .

Comment: Couldn't find anything either. Perhaps over at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com they know of one. Otherwise you'll have to do some coding yourself to automate it. You could start by looking at how the [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin does it (you already seem to script part of it [using the add_image_size](https://www.google.com/search?q=wp+add_image_size). You can use `$wpdb` or `WP_Query` to query all images and/or shops and set the sizes you want, per shop.

Comment: thx but can you explain that more in detail?

Comment: I've been thinking about it, but I'm still unclear on what you are attempting. If you do `add_image_size( 'shop_catalog', '275', '200', ['center','center'])` - (where, btw? could you show us some code?) - then you are setting this globally. That means that (for the duration of the request) the `shop_catalog` image size is `275x200`. Your (affiliate) shop will then try to use *that* image size *for all products* - and many will not exist. Have you split up the products in the catalog by shop, and are you setting those image sizes in a hook, based on what part of the catalog is browsed, perhaps?

Comment: I mean i change the image size. this code appears when i click on "get php code for your theme" on settings / media. then i go to media and search the images if the right shop ( that have to be cropped and resized by this setting ) when i choose all the images from the shop i regenerate them. This i repeat with every single shop. perhaps its a lot of work when i have to repeat this every day because everyday there are new products ( and their images ) added. Sry for my bad english and my noob skills :D and thx for you help. i hope this made it a bit clear

Comment: So *why* are you *generating* different sizes of images depending on shop? You show *all products* from all those shops in your theme, right? And the theme/woo uses `shop_catalog` to find out how big catalog images should be, and then fetch the matching image. Changing the size via `add_image_size` only makes sense if different pages in your wp use different values for `shop_catalog` image - are they?

Comment: because all shops have different sizes and the worst part most of them have white space around so they have to be cropped. I want that all products look almost the same.